# How can I install a smart switch that needs a neutral wire?

Tags: wiring, neutral, smart-switch

I have already replaced some existing dumb switches with smart ones
However, I am having trouble understanding the connection in the switch box that controls a light fixture on my wall in the staircase to my basement that I want to swap for a Lutron Caseta claro so that I can pair it with a smart motion sensor.

There are 2 sets of wires coming into the switch box. The first set has 4 wires (black, red, white, and ground). The second set has only 3 wires (black, white, and ground)

Connection of 4 wire set:

- Red wire is connected to the dumb dimmer
- White wire is not connected
- Ground is connected to the box
- Black is connected to the white from the other set of 3 wires

Connection of 3 wire set:

- black connected to a dumb dimmer
- white connected to black of other set of 4 wires
- ground connected to box

I am not sure how to connect my Lutron Claro switch with this setup and i would appreciate some help

**note**:

- I didn't open the box for the light fixture yet
- My voltmeter is broken and needs to get a new one - so I couldn't check any voltage on the wires

[image]

Comment: you can use the No-contact tester

Comment: Was there another switch that controlled this light?  Also, is replacing any of the wiring an option?

Comment: This one is getting me confused. Do you know where the cable with the red wire goes? Do you know where the cable without the red wire goes?

Comment: The red wire in the cable of 4 indicates that you've _most likely_ got a 3-way switch for this light, even if you don't know it. I'd suggest that you open up the light fixture and get a pic of the wiring there for us to look at (don't disconnect anything, of course).